# Usage of @final keyword

Tags: swift

When I try to define a variable preceded with a @final keyword:

```
    class SomeClassX{
     @final var x: String
     var y: String
     init(y: String) {
         self.y = y
     }
    }
```

I get an error:

> 'final' is a declaration modifier, not an attribute

I find this really weird because Swift Programming Language book says

> You can prevent a method, property, or subscript from being overridden
>   by marking it as final. Do this by writing the @final **attribute**
>   before its introducer keyword

How should i use it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using a very out-of-date version of the language guide. Since Swift 1.0, `final` is a keyword not an attribute. Just remove the `@`.

You can see this change in the Revision History of the guide.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for `@` preceding `final`. The thing is that you did the compiler is interpreting `final` as an attribute, such as `@available`. Therefore:

```
class SomeClassX{
  final var x: String

  var y: String
  init(y: String) {
    self.y = y
  }
}
```